# Javascript doesn't run in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I tried to look in other similar posts but apparently, I did something wrong somewhere without me noticing it as my PHP, HTML and JavaScript skills are very outdated. Last I touched these things was last year, so a lot of my fault detection skills are rusty.

That being said, the piece of code I'm trying to do is structured like this

> ```
> <?PHP //If?> 
> JS //Script to check if input is empty and prevents submission
> HTML <!--Input Forms-->
> <?PHP //DB actions ?>
> ```

As far as I can do, the syntax of the PHP seems correct (used php formatter to check if my syntax is wrong). The problem here is the javascript portion does not even run. And if it runs, the remainder of the UI (login form) disappears for no reason (when input is supplied).

Below is the code I'm using.

```
        <?php
        if(empty($_POST["username"]) && empty($_POST["password"])){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javacsript">
        function checkField()
                    {
            if((login-form.username.value == "") || (login-form.password.value == ""))
                        {
                            alert("Please fill in both Username and Password fields");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                            return true;
                    }
        </script>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form" id="login-form" action="login.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkField();">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username" type="text" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password" value="">
                            </div>
                            <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                            <!--<a href="index.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a>-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
        <?php
        }else {
            $message = "wrong answer";
            echo "1<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }
        ?>
```

JavaScript for onsubmit is the main concern here. It does not even run when the supposed true condition is triggered (when either of the inputs are empty or both are empty). And the secondary script below, is just my initial test run before supplying the database portion.

## Edit 1

Alt code for checkField() using getElementById

```
        <script type="text/javacsript">
        function checkField()
                    {
            if((document.getElementById("username").value == "") || (document.getElementById("password").value == ""))
                        {
                            alert("Please fill in both Username and Password fields");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                            return true;
                    }
        </script>
```

## Edit 2

After resolving the typo, the PHP portion which is triggered when both login and password fields are not empty does not run at all. The action attribute might have a hand

```
<form role="form" id="login_form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return checkField();">
```

The code above is to test if the action attribute is the culprit. Still the result is the same. The page will reload with empty fields.

Latest code

```
        <?php
        if(empty($_POST["username"]) && empty($_POST["password"])){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkField()
                    {
            if((document.getElementById("username").value == "") || (document.getElementById("password").value == ""))
                        {
                            alert("Please fill in both Username and Password fields");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                            return true;
                    }
        </script>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form" id="login_form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return checkField();">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username" type="text" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password" value="">
                            </div>
                            <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                            <!--<a href="index.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a>-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
        <?php
        }else {
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","rootacc","test");
            if($conn)
            {
                echo "success";
                header("LOCATION:tables.html");
            }
        }
        ?>
```

## Edit 3

All problems resolved. Sorry for the newbie question, thank you for all who contributed. Here's the corrected code

```
        <?php
        if(empty($_POST["username"]) && empty($_POST["password"])){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkField()
                    {
            if((document.getElementById("username").value == "") || (document.getElementById("password").value == ""))
                        {
                            alert("Please fill in both Username and Password fields");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                            return true;
                    }
        </script>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form" id="login_form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return checkField();">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                            </div>
                            <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                            <!--<a href="index.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a>-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
        <?php
        }else {
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","rootacc","test");
            if($conn)
            {
                echo "success";
                header("LOCATION:tables.html");
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Issue 1 is due to my own programming sloppiness (using dash instead of other styles of variable referencing) as well as the lack of knowledge on getElementById
Issue 2 is due to my own typo which wasn't spotted. 
Issue 3 is due to the lack of understanding on id and name (seems the same)

All recommendation to fix the issues are implemented.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: "the javascript portion does not even run. And if it runs..." So which is it? Does it run or not?

Comment: `login-form.username.value` - this statement _subtracts_ `form.username.value` from `login`, which is not what you want. And since relying on the browser to automatically create global variables referencing elements with ids is a real bad practice anyway, you want to go use `document.getElementById` instead to get references to your input fields.

Comment: @PatrickQ the JS portion I mentioned was the one made within PHP tag (sorry for the ambiguous statement) while the ones I made in the script tag doesn't even run. Still, I forgot what I did, now both doesn't.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Console from Edge -> NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR): GET - http://localhost/fyp/assets/plugins/jquery.min.map

Comment: @CBroe what do you mean by subtract? I tried to change it into underscore (login_form.username.value), it doesn't invoke the JS either. I have not tried the getElementById as I learned the coding style from a very old source. Might be useful if there is an example to use in the similar context to what I'm trying to do

Comment: _"what do you mean by subtract?"_ - essential part of basic JS syntax: `-` is the subtraction _operator_, and can not be part of variable names. _"I have not tried the getElementById as I learned the coding style from a very old source"_ - well there's your problem :) Go find more current sources, and go read up on some essential basics. Getting your skills up to date is primarily your job, and not SO's.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the reminder that updating my skill is my job. Doesn't work either with getElementById

Comment: If you are not even sure whether your problem is actually in the PHP part or the JS part - then eliminate the former. Write the complete page in static HTML and JS, and see to it that you get that to work as intended. Once you got that done, you can add in the PHP again. If it stops working then - then you compare the HTML output created by your PHP script to the static version, and find out what is different.

Comment: Your script tag has a typo. javascript not javacsript. `<script type="text/javascript">` is the proper tag. With that said, you should definitely use your alternate script code since @CBroe is correct about not using operators in your element name.

Comment: @PatrickH. Thank you for spotting that typo. I've edited the question for the next problem. The PHP part which should be triggered when both username and password are field doesn't run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post parameters are not set, that may be the reason it's not going to ELSE condition.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" type="password" value="">
</div>
```

Use, "name" attribute to set the POST parameters.